# Creating block matrix via loop

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to create a block matrix using a loop in R, which depend on some variable I call T. The two matrices used to construct the block matrix could look like this:

```
A=matrix(c(1,0.3,0.3,1.5),nrow=2)

B=matrix(c(0.5,0.3,0.3,1.5),nrow=2)
```

So depending on what i set T to, I need different results. For T=2:

```
C=rbind(cbind(A,B),cbind(B,A))
```

For T=3:

```
C=rbind(cbind(A,B,B),cbind(B,A,B),cbind(B,B,A))
```

For T=5:

```
C=rbind(cbind(A,B,B,B,B),cbind(B,A,B,B,B),cbind(B,B,A,B,B),cbind(B,B,B,A,B),cbind(B,B,B,B,A))
```

So basically, I'm just trying to create a loop or something similar, where I can just specify my T and it will create the block matrix for me depending on T.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
N <- nrow(A)
C <- matrix(NA,N*T,N*T)
for (i in 1:T){
   for (j in 1:T){
     if (i == j)
        C[(i-1)*N+1:N, (j-1)*N+1:N] <- A
     else
        C[(i-1)*N+1:N, (j-1)*N+1:N] <- B
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I suppose that you want single A and T-1 Bs in your final matrix.

If that is correct then here is a quick try using the permn function from the combinat library. All I am doing is generating the expression using the permutation and then evaluating it.

```
A = matrix(c(1,0.3,0.3,1.5),nrow=2)
B = matrix(c(0.5,0.3,0.3,1.5),nrow=2)
T = 5
x = c("A", rep("B",T-1))
perms = unique(permn(x)) #permn generates non-unique permutations
perms = lapply(perms, function(xx) {xx=paste(xx,collapse=","); xx=paste("cbind(",xx,")")})
perms = paste(perms, collapse=",")
perms = paste("C = rbind(",perms,")",collapse=",")
eval(parse(text=perms))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My computer seems to be crashing, if I set T too high. I guess the number of permutations gets too high. I don't know, if there is a way to work around this?

Comment: I wont recommend this for high values of T, as you said number of permutations can become quite large.

Answer (score 0):

With the `blockmatrix` package this is pretty straightforward.

```
library(blockmatrix)

# create toy matrices (block matrix elements)
# with values which makes it easier to track them in the block matrix in the example here
A <- matrix("a", nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
B <- matrix("b", nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

# function for creating the block matrix
# n: number of repeating blocks in each dimension
# (I use n instead of T, to avoid confusion with T as in TRUE)
# m_list: the two matrices in a list

block <- function(n, m_list){      
  # create a 'layout matrix' of the block matrix elements
  m <- matrix("B", nrow = n, ncol = n)
  diag(m) <- "A"

  # build block matrix
  as.matrix(blockmatrix(dim = dim(m_list[[1]]), value = m, list = m_list))
}

# try with different n
block(n = 2, m_list = list(A = A, B = B))
block(n = 3, m_list = list(A = A, B = B))
block(n = 5, m_list = list(A = A, B = B))
```